# ADB and Xcode are not detecting connected devices, after update to Catalina mac os

Tags: macos, iphone, catalina, android

ADB and Xcode are not detecting connected devices, after update to Catalina mac os. Did any one of them faced the issue after upgrade.

Please let me know the solution to fix this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) What is the version of macOS Catalina that you are running? And the version of iOS/iPadOS on your devices? Can you see the devices in any other apps such as Music or Finder?

Comment: I am using 10.15.4 (19E287). Android devices--version 10 & 9. Iphone -13.3.1..I am not able to see the devices in other apps also.

Comment: Obligatory, is your device unlocked? Are you confident the cable isn't faulty? Does the devices show up on a different computer (Mac or Windows). Are you using a single multi-connector cable to connect Android and iOS devices together or one by one?

Comment: Nope..cable is working fine..this happening only after the mac upgrade to catalina..When I open the mac in safemode adb is showing devices..but when i open in normal mode adb is not showing...Immediately after mac restart xcode is showing iphone..if we remove and connect it is not showing..